# Problem while trying to install some packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am trying to execute this code:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential autoconf automake automake1.9 cmake doxygen bison flex libncurses5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libreadline-dev libusb-dev texinfo libgmp3-dev libmpfr-dev libelf-dev libmpc-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev libtool libtool-bin subversion git tcl unzip
```

However I get this problem:

```
Package automake is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'automake' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package automake1.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'automake1.9'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'automake1.9'
E: Unable to locate package doxygen
E: Unable to locate package libsdl1.2-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libsdl1.2-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libsdl1.2-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libgmp3-dev
E: Unable to locate package libmpfr-dev
E: Unable to locate package libelf-dev
E: Unable to locate package libmpc-dev
E: Unable to locate package libtool-bin
```

I have tried to use `sudo apt-get update` but I still get this error! Any idea?

The output of `grep "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.panda3d.org/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://archive.panda3d.org/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe main restricted multiverse
```

Comment: Do you have the Universe repository enabled in Software & Updates?

Comment: What is the output of `grep "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: The Universe repository is enabled!

Answer (score 0):

try to update the source list :

Ubuntu Main Repos

> deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: DrunkProgrammer already has a line that says `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe main restricted multiverse` in his `/etc/apt/sources.list` so your answer would change nothing.

Comment: no it's not the same sever i use french location

Comment: It produces the same result with both server locations, because the two URLs are mirrors of each other.